# I can't access a property of an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm accessing an object from the database. Here is the object I get:

```json
{
 data: {
  settings: {
   language: 'en-US'
  }
 }
}
```

I'm trying to access the language part, but somehow it's not working,
this is my code:

```js
translate(key, args, base) {
  const language = base.data.settings.language
  const result = this.translation.get(base ? language : 'en-GB')
  ...
  return result;
}
```

My problem is that the object isn't defined in that result (this part: `this.translation.get(base ? language : 'en-GB')`)

The data is defined, I've tried `console.log(language)` and it's returning `en-US` :

```js
const language = base.data.settings.language
console.log(language) // en-US
const result = this.translation.get(base ? language : 'en-GB') // cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

But when I change the `language` variable to a string like `const language = "en-US"` it's working for both of them. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Which object isn’t defined? Where is `translate` defined and how is it called? If `base.data` is `undefined`, as the error message suggests, then the line `const language = base.data.settings.language` would already have thrown that error, not the one that calls `this.translation.get`.

Comment: I would suggest that the problem is inside the `translation` function. Can you show us the code

Comment: Can you paste the implementation of `translation` ?

Comment: Is your translation.get function trying to access base.data.settings??

Comment: @SebastianSimon it's called pretty simple just app.translate(text, change, data), but isn't throwing problem with consoleLog

Comment: here's the translation
https://pastebin.com/Cn5vke0D also there's no problem here, it's working for other functions

Comment: Are you sure the error `'cannot read property 'settings' of undefined'` is really thrown at the line `const result = this.translation.get(base ? language : 'en-GB')`, not other line?

Comment: @RickyMo im not really sure, because the error saying from the first line but it's perfectly fine with logging it. I just assume from there because when calling translation part the error coming

Comment: If error has been thrown from the first line, the console.log at the second line wouldn't be able to run.

Comment: yes it won't, but the first line error only throwing when I call the translation part

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that base is an optional parameter. That explains the `cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` error which should actually appear on the *first* line of your code. You need to change your code as follows:

```
const language = base ? base.data.settings.language : "en-GB";
```

If there is a possibility that the path does not exist then the safer solution is this:

```
const language = base?.data?.settings?.language ?? "en-GB";
```

Comment: OP mentioned `console.log(language) //returning en-US`, also the error was thrown in the third line, not the first line.

Comment: But it looks like he is trying to use a fallback language `en-GB` and all the code examples are doing it wrong.

Comment: But this does not explain the observation with the given code. If OP doesn't lie (all information given by OP is true), then this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @RickyMo But why does it work when assigning "en-US" to language? If I understand correctly myself, the error lies in the first line.

Comment: @jperl I think so. So I too doubt OP is giving wrong information. Though keep trusting before can prove OP wrong.

Comment: Now OP has admitted that the error is thrown at the first line :)

Answer (score 2):

```
const result = this.translation.get(base ? language : 'en-GB')
```

In the ^above line, you pass the parameter after checking if the `base` is nullish or not.

But At the same time in previous line, `const language = base.data.settings.language` you already access the `base` object regardless of it being nullish. That doesn't make sense.

Also,

> but if I change the language variable to a string like const language = "en-US" it's working for both of them, am I doing this wrong?

^This means the issue is with that line

I suggest you to add the nullish check there, like below:

```
const language = base ? base.data.settings.language : 'en-GB';
const result = this.translation.get(language)
```

Comment: I've try that before but just the same result